# How to use Variable and UserKeyword from test case level, which created at project level

Tags: robotframework

How to use Variable and UserKeyword from test case level, which created at project level.

I have a robot framework project like:

```
Project
       Suite1
             TC_001
             TC_002
       Suite2
             TC_003
             TC_004
```

I have create `Variable` and `UserKeyword` at project level and I want to use those `Variable` and `UserKeyword` from test case level. My question is, how to use them at test case level?

Comment: Under Settings you have to call the file as resource.

Example: Let say you have ${username}=   Random in suite1.robot. You have to call suite1.robot in file you want to use

```*** Settings *** 
    Resource    Suite1.robot

    *** Test Case ***
    Suite Variable Check
        Log    ${username}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html) there are two sections you may want to go through in more detail:

- [Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables)
- [Resource and variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files)

Both of these describe how to import variables and external keywords from external files. In essence a resource file is a regular robot file but without the test cases. It only contains keywords and has the regular settings and variable sections. It can be imported in your test suite file through the `Resource    common.robot` construct:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          common.robot
Resource          feature_1.robot
Resource          feature_2.robot


*** Variables ***
${HOST}           localhost:7272

*** Keywords ***
Open Login Page
    Do something
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, one more question could you please tell me the best practice naming conversion of Resource file where more than one word?

Comment: Can i use multiple resources file under one suite?

Comment: As the resource name is the file name your limitations are typically the ones imposed by your OS. So I'd stick with either `CamelCase` or use of `under_scores `. As you can also use directory names `./common/browser.robot` and `./common/general.robot` or ./application/feature/function.robot` make for a good way to keep your code maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to import the file created in the "Project" directory, and afterwards you'll have access to the variables and keywords defined in it.

If the file there is called "The_project_file.robot", in "Suite_1.robot":

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    ../The_project_file.robot

*** Test Case ***
TC_001
    Log    ${variable defined in The_project_file}
    ${value}=    Keyword Defined In The Project File
```